# SES emails dyamic using nodejs and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-ses

I am using node-ses to send an email which is working fine

```
client.sendEmail({
   to: to_id,
 , cc: cc_id,
 , bcc: bcc_id,
 , subject: 'greetings'
 , message: 'your <b>message</b> goes here'
 , altText: 'plain text'
}, function (err, data, res) {
 // ...
});
```

Now problem is that if **cc_id is empty or NULL**, then it errors out and saying cc_id is required. if i skip cc_id from above code it works.

I tried this script

```
if (typeof bcc_email_id !== 'undefined' && bcc_email_id != null) {
    bcc_email_id = bcc_email_id.split(",");
    emailStr.push('bcc:' + bcc_email_id);    
}               
if (typeof cc_email_id !== 'undefined' && cc_email_id != null) {
    cc_email_id = cc_email_id.split(",");
    emailStr += 'cc:' + cc_email_id;
}
```

and

```
client.sendEmail({
  emailStr,
   , subject: 'greetings'
   , message: 'your <b>message</b> goes here'
   , altText: 'plain text'
  }, function (err, data, res) {
   // ...
});
```

but it didnt worked. Any idea how to make it dynamic,

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some validation code in `node-ses` that checks that if the `cc` property is present, then it must not be `null` nor an empty string.

Try changing line 3 into:

```
, cc: cc_id || undefined
```

That way, the validation code will assume the `cc` property is not present and will not try to validate it.

The validation code will assume the property is not present because the code `cc_id || undefined` will return `undefined` if `cc_id` is `null` or empty, and if a property is not present then trying to access it evaluates to `undefined`.